# Have I designed and routed my USB-C port correctly because when I connect my 3D printer I measure voltage on vcc

Tags: esp32, usb-c, routing, diagram

I have designed my usb-c connection as in the attached pictures, however whenever I connect my Ender-3 to it I measure between 1-2V on different parts of the circuit including the data pins on the ESP32-S3 that drives the logic of the circuit. I connected the printer's usb port to a breakout to measure the voltages and I get 2.6V on the red wire and 3.3V on D- during idle, I also modified the cable to sever the red wire(VBUS). My best guess currently as to what the issue is is that I have not wired the USBLC6(https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108132230_TECH-PUBLIC-USBLC6-2SC6_C2827654.pdf) chip correctly. Can anyone verify this for me please as I was not sure how to wire it up from the start but it looked correct? Or if you spot anything else that I might have done wrong concerning the USB port wiring.
[image]

[image]

EDIT:
So I found that the issue is that when the board is completely unpowered but there is Voltage on D- or D+, parasitic voltage leaks everywhere on the board including VCC and IO's. To hopefully remedy this I found this https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2303011730_Texas-Instruments-TS3USB31RSER_C2649441.pdf USB switch chip. I implemented it as follows.

[image]

[image]

AS I don't need VBUS I disconnected it along with the BAT60. The switch also has ESD so I removed the usblc6-2sc6 as well.

From the switch's datasheet I gathered that it puts the chip in a high impedence state that isolates the bus thus when VCC is not connected but data lines active. This gives me what I want by not letting current through while my board is off but usb cable connected. Is my logic and implementation correct?

Comment: It is unclear what this design do. Can you explain what is the intent behind this circuit. Can you also explain what failure your are seeing and under which conditions.

Comment: This circuit makes no sense. The plug is configured as device but it pushes 5V with diode to PC. Is this device supposed to be a host or a device?

Comment: Shield is not connected, guaranteeing ambient noise disrupts the connection.

Comment: connection of usblc6-2sc6 looks ok

Comment: The purpose of the usb port is to provide basic serial comms to the device. This works as it should but if I remove power from the circuit and leave just the usb cable attached I measure 1.9V on the io pins as well as vcc in the circuit. I thought it was due to incorrect routing of the usb and usblc6 but I tried with a micro usb port with only d+ and d- connected. Roughly same measurement. I think the next step for me would be to desolder the esp32 and just connect d+ and d- and measure the pins again?